# App script - Trouble in removing Tables since the 11st

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've done a google doc template that I'm modifying on the basis of the inserted value in a google sheet.

I've this kind of problem, once I've defined the google doc document I've to remove some tables and I'm doing like this:

```
Var Table1 = body.getTables()[1];
Var Table2 = body.getTables()[2];
....
Var Table15 = body.getTables()[15];

Table1.RemoveFromParent();
Table2.RemoveFromParent();
...
Table15.RemoveFromParent();
```

All Works till the 10th Table, at the 11th an error box appear with

> "TypeError: Impossible call the method "removeFromParent" of undefined

. It seems like app script cannot recognize Table from to 11st to the next ones.

But the weirdest thing is that I've tried to change the position of the tables in the doc and sometimes the script recognizes the tables between the 11 and the 15, others does not.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a document with 5 tables:

```js
Logger.log(body.getTables().length) // Outputs: 5.0
var table0 = body.getTables()[0];
var table1 = body.getTables()[1];
var table2 = body.getTables()[2];
var table3 = body.getTables()[3];
var table4 = body.getTables()[4];
```

Once you do:

```js
table2.removeFromParent();
```

Now 
`table4` is referencing something that does not exist anymore:

```js
var table4 = body.getTables()[4];
```

is `undefined`, because there are know only 4 tables left:

```js
Logger.log(body.getTables().length) // Outputs: 4.0
var table0 = body.getTables()[0]; //same
var table1 = body.getTables()[1]; //same
var table2 = body.getTables()[2]; //this is now table 3
var table3 = body.getTables()[3]; //this is now table 4
var table4 = body.getTables()[4]; //undefined, does not exist.
```

There are  only 4 tables now: 0, 1, 2 & 3.